# Padding not showing up in tkinter grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I have tried making a basic tkinter ttk program, but the frame's padding between each other is gone. I am using grid, which should have (maybe) caused the problem. I am a beginner and I require help. Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def donothing():
    print("i see")

root = Tk()
root.title("Application")
root.geometry("1000x1000")

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure('TFrame', background='gray')
s.configure('windowframes.TFrame', background='darkgray')

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="5 5 5 5",height=300)
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,E,S,W))


menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
filemenu = Menu(menu,tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save as...", command=donothing)
filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=donothing)

filemenu.add_separator()

filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

toolframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,padding="5 5 5 5",height=40,style='windowframes.TFrame')
toolframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,E,W))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0,weight=2)

hierarchyframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,padding="5 5 5 5",width=300,style='windowframes.TFrame')
hierarchyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(S,W,N))
mainframe.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It doesn't look like the frames overlap to me, and looking at the code I don't see how it's possible that they do. Why do you think they overlap?

Comment: I see. I thought they overlapped because the padding did not affect the frames, so the dark grey background showed that either the padding did not affect, or one frame was going into another. Is there any way to fix the padding issue?

Comment: If you want paddings between frames, add `padx` and `pady` options in `.grid(...)`, like `toolframe.grid(..., padx=5, pady=5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acw1668 was right, just change it from making the Frame and putting padding there, instead put it in .grid function, as in

```
hierarchyframe = ttk.Frame(mainframe,width=300,style='windowframes.TFrame')
hierarchyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=(S,W,N), padx=2, pady=2)
```

Thank you